# C++ Short Circuit Evaluation

Tags: c++, short-circuiting

Maybe I am missing something rather simple, but I am getting a crash when I dereference a pointer even though I check the point at the very beginning of the expression.

```
if( var1 &&
    bool1 || bool2 &&
    var1->DoSomething() )
{

}
```

var1 is a null pointer, but Var1->Dosomething() is still being called. My understanding is that the && and the || operator in C++ are short circuit so if var1 was null then it would just terminate at the very beginning. Or is there something else I am missing?

Comment: When in doubt, **parenthesize**!

Answer (score 12):

[Operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) is the key here. Because `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, your expression is equivalent to

```
(var1 && bool1) || (bool2 && var1->DoSomething() )
```

So, since `var1` evaluates to false, `bool1` is not evaluated and `(var1 && bool1)` yields false, therefore  `(bool2 && var1->DoSomething())` has to be evaluated. And if `bool2` happens to be true, then `var1->DoSomething()` will also be evaluated, resulting in undefined behavior.

Just add some parentheses (for the specific expression tree that you require) and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Since `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, your expression is parsed as `(var1 && bool1) || (bool2 && var1->DoSomething())`. Now since `var1` is a null pointer, short circuit evaluation means that `bool1` is not evaluated, and the left hand side of `||` evaluates as false. Thus to find out the value of the expression, the right hand side has to be evaluated (i.e. short-circuit evaluation does *not* kick in here!). The right hand side of `||` is `bool2 && var1->DoSomething()`, thus if `bool2` is true, `var1->DoSomething()` will be evaluated. Note also that even for `var1` non-null, the result of the eexpression will not always be what you probably expected.

Answer (score 1):

Simple.
&& has higher precedence so your expression reads:

```
if( ( var1 && bool1 ) || ( bool2 && var1->DoSomething()) )
```

try

```
if( var1 && ( bool1 || bool2 ) && var1->DoSomething() )
```

otherwise the first expression `car1 && bool1` fails and the second expression is evaluated. since bool2 returns true apparently your pointer is dereferenced if bool2 is true.

look here for a precedencelist: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence or use google.